# Redirect stdin/out to pipe and use in child process

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pipe

I'm writing a simple application which will use anonymous pipes to communicate with child process called using `execl()`.
Child process is simple echo application.
I want to redirect `stdin` and `stdout` to pipes and use them to receive data sent by child in parent.
Now only two lines are echoed.
Any ideas what is wrong?

Here is my code:
(parent.c)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
int parent_to_child[2];
int child_to_parent[2];

if(pipe(parent_to_child) == -1) exit(-1);
if(pipe(child_to_parent) == -1) exit(-1);

switch(fork())
{
    case -1: exit(-1);

    case 0: //child
         if(close(0) == -1) exit(-1);
         if(dup(parent_to_child[0]) != 0) exit(-1);
             fprintf(stderr, "stdin changed\n");
         if(close(1) == -1) exit(-1);
         if(dup(child_to_parent[1]) != 1) exit(-1);
             fprintf(stderr, "stdout changed\n");
         close(parent_to_child[0]);
         close(parent_to_child[1]);
         close(child_to_parent[0]);
         close(child_to_parent[1]);

         execl("./child_process","child_process", (char*)NULL);
         exit(-1);
    default: //parent

         close(parent_to_child[0]);
         close(child_to_parent[1]);
         size_t size = 1024;
         char* line = (char *) malloc(size);
         while(getline(&line, &size, stdin) != -1)
         {
             if(write(parent_to_child[1], line, (strlen(line)+1)*sizeof(char)) == -1)
             {
                printf("%d", errno);
                exit(-1);
             }
             read(child_to_parent[0], line, size);
             printf("%s", line);
         }
}
return 0;
}
```

(child_process.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
size_t size = 1024;
char* line = (char*) malloc(size);

setlinebuf(stdout);
setlinebuf(stdin);
fprintf(stderr, "child started\n");
while(getline(&line, &size, stdin) != -1)
{
    printf("%s", line);
}
fprintf(stderr, "exiting");
free(line);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indent consistently and do not use tabs for indenting

Comment: Always a good idea, when exiting because of an error, to inform the user as to what the error is.   This is normally accomplished by calling `perror()` before calling `exit()`.   Before calling `exit()` the code should cleanup an open files, release an malloc'd memory, etc  This includes closing any pipe fds.

Comment: regarding these three lines: `  size_t size = 1024;
             char* line = (char *) malloc(size);
             while(getline(&line, &size, stdin) != -1)`  getline() performs a realloc() and sets the value in size.  suggest: `size_t size=0; char *line = NULL; ...`

Comment: all three of the switch() cases need to (eventually) close all 4 of the pipe fds

Comment: the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard a 1.   multiplying by 1 has absolutely no effect on the rest of the multiplication, however, it does clutter the code.   Suggest removing the expression

Comment: regarding this line: `printf("%d", errno);`  some 'strange' number being printed on the terminal will mean little to nothing to the user of your application.  Suggest: `perror( "write() from parent to child failed" );` as this will output the message to stderr and append the relevant system error message that indicates why the write failed

Comment: the returned value from a call to `read()` needs to be checked to assure the read was successful.,   When calling `dup()` the new file descriptor is returned.  The code needs that new file descriptor, so it needs to be set into a 'int' variable,  Note: it is necessary to close stdin/stdout before calling dup() so the right file descriptor is used.  You could use dup2() to force the right file descriptor to be set.